# Include map scale and north arrow to only one ggplot facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am ploting a map using the `ggplot2` and `sf` packages and I would like to include a map scale and north arrow to the figure using the [`ggsn`](https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn) package. Here is the problem. I want to show a figure with two or more `facets` but I would like to add the scale and north arrow to only one of the figure facets.

Any idea on how to do this?

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(UScensus2000tract)
library(ggplot2)
library(spdep)
library(sf)
library(ggsn)

# load data
  data("oregon.tract")

# convert spatial object to sf class
  oregon_sf_A <- st_as_sf(oregon.tract)
  oregon_sf_B <- st_as_sf(oregon.tract)

# organize data for facetting
  oregon_sf_A$cat <- "A"
  oregon_sf_B$cat <- "B"
  oregon_sf <- rbind(oregon_sf_A, oregon_sf_B)

# create a second variable for facetting
  oregon_sf$var2 <- sample(c("C","D"), nrow(oregon_sf), replace=T)

# Map
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data=oregon_sf, aes(fill=hispanic.t), color=NA) +
    scale_fill_viridis(option = "inferno", direction=-1) +
    facet_grid(~cat) +
    north(data=oregon_sf, symbol=4, location="bottomleft", scale=.2) +
    scalebar(data=oregon_sf, dist = 200, st.size=3, height=0.02, dd2km = TRUE, location="bottomright" , model = 'WGS84')
```

[image]

The problem gets a bit more complicated if we try to use two variables in `facet_grid`:

```
# Map 2
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data=oregon_sf, aes(fill=hispanic.t), color=NA) +
    scale_fill_viridis(option = "inferno", direction=-1) +
    facet_grid(cat~var2) +
    north(data=oregon_sf, symbol=4, location="bottomleft", scale=.2) +
    scalebar(data=oregon_sf, dist = 200, st.size=3, height=0.02, dd2km = TRUE, location="bottomright" , model = 'WGS84')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the facet.var and facet.lev arguments in scalebar to add to a single facet. Use the north2() function to add a single north arrow. You can adjust the positioning/scale etc. to suit your needs.
If you are using facet_grid with two variables you can pass a vector to facet.var and facet.lev.

```
 ggp <- ggplot(data = oregon_sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=hispanic.t), color=NA) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "inferno", direction=-1) +
  facet_grid(cat~var2) +
  scalebar(data=oregon_sf, dist = 200, st.size=3, height=0.02, dd2km = TRUE, location="bottomright" , model = 'WGS84',
           facet.var = c('cat', 'var2'), facet.lev = c('B', "C"))
north2(ggp = ggp, scale = 0.1, x = 0.05, y = 0.3, symbol = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: `oregon.tract` is part of `UScensus2000tract` package which OP linked to

Comment: thanks! I have updated my answer to use the OP's data

Comment: Thanks @sebdalgarno, that's very helpful. However, I noticed that `facet.var` and `facet.lev` don't seem to work when I use `facet_grid` with two variables so I've expanded the question to address this situation as well.

Comment: see edits...you can simply pass a vector to facet.var and facet.lev

Comment: @rafa.pereira please mark the question as answered if those edits did indeed work for you.

Comment: this is a brilliant package indeed. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't discovered it yet, the ggspatial package has a solution for this here.  https://github.com/paleolimbot/ggspatial/issues/25